# How to create an iOS 7 app that installs over the air

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, xcode6

I am quite a newbiew in iOS developing/deployment and other stuffs related to iOS.

I made a simple presentation app but my task contains also the delivering stage. I must create a **link from which the users can directly install the application** on their iPads. I've been through a lot of posts but many of them are outdated.(For example I don't have any "Share" button when creating the archive), or are not explicit enough. **So how can I build an application and provide an html from which the application will automatically install?**

To be mentioned:

1. the ipa will be stored on dropbox
2. it's an iOS 7 application project
3. I use XCode 6.1

Can someone help please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have two choices, make an adhoc or an inhouse, before going further on the answer, do you have a simple apple developer account or is it a enterprise apple developer account?

Comment: Is it a private app, perhaps for internal business use? An enterprise developer account will let you do this.

Comment: I used enterprise account.

Comment: For those of you who down vote any questions or answers please write down your reasons! It will be much productive that way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need a html file containing a link like this one:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://linkToYourFolder/YourAppsName.plist">
```

The https on the link on your html file is absolutly needed if i remember right.

Now, the plist will look like the following.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>items</key>
        <array>
                <dict>
                        <key>assets</key>
                        <array>
                                <dict>
                                        <key>kind</key>
                                        <string>software-package</string>
                                        <key>url</key>
                                        <string>https://linkToYourFolder/YourAppsName.ipa</string>
                                </dict>
                        </array>
                        <key>metadata</key>
                        <dict>
                                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                                <string>com.your.bundle.identifier</string>
                                <key>bundle-version</key>
                                <string>1.0.0</string>
                                <key>kind</key>
                                <string>software</string>
                                <key>title</key>
                                <string>YourAppsName</string>
                        </dict>
                </dict>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Before xCode 6, xcode would ask you if you wanted to generate a plist file when exporting the ipa. Since xCode 6 i haven't found how to generate it, so i use the same base.plist file and modify what's needed. (If someone knows how to generate that file on xCode 6, feel free to comment :D)

To generate the app.ipa file, go on xCode window menu => Organizer => select the archive you wish to export, and save it as an enterprise build.

Something important before compiling your Archive, you need to set the provisioning profile on the configuration you'll use to make the archive.
At my work we usually copy the release configuration and rename it inHouse. Then in the scheme for archiving we select the inHouse configuration which has the provisioningProfile needed to make the ipa, set in the project/target build settings.

You should know that you can also do the same for an adhoc, the only difference that i know of, is that the adhoc will be limited to the maximum 100 devices from the adhoc mobileProvisioning. Use adhoc if you don't have an enterprise apple developer account.

Answer (score 0):

firstly for OTA build u need universal distribution profile using enterprize developer account. You need .ipa, .plist and html file.

1.Select universal distribution profile.

2.Select product-->Archieve-->Distribution.

3.Check on “Enterprise Edition”.

4.Write Application url/.ipa file name.

5.Add title “Wireless Ad-hoc Demo”and Save as “WirelessAdhocDemo.ipa”.Click “Save” Button at the bottom of the page.(Refer “http://gknops.github.io/adHocGenerate/” for detail information).